# Как вывести json

Tags: python

Как вывести json ответ красиво

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/insert-key-here/insert-value-here/key/value')
print(response.json())
```

На выводе получаю это : `{'insert-key-here': 'insert-value-here', 'key': 'value'}`
Что необходимо сделать чтобы получить ответ типа :

```
1 : insert-value-here
2 : value
```

Comment: `for k, v in response.json().items(): print(k, ':', v)`

Comment: Или `for i, v in enumerate(response.json().values(), 1): print(i, ':', v)`